# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I got an error when I was trying to join two datasets which are from database and csv file
the error message is like this:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 14.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 14, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, targetString), StringType), true, false) AS targetString#205
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, deviceName), StringType), true, false) AS deviceName#206
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, alarmDetectionCode), StringType), true, false) AS alarmDetectionCode#207
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:292)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write
```

It looked like mismatch happened when spark application was joining two dataset
with different schema , but I don't know how it happened.
My java code like this:

```
Dataset result = null;
result = deviceInfoDataset.join(searchInfo,deviceInfoDataset.col("deviceName").equalTo(searchInfo.col("deviceName")));
result.show();
```

Dataset schema:

```
device
+--------+----------+----------+
|ctgry_cd|deviceInfo|deviceName|
+--------+----------+----------+
searchinfo
+------------+----------+------------------+
|targetString|deviceName|alarmDetectionCode|
+------------+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
`deviceInfoDataset.join(searchInfo,"deviceName").show()`

Comment: yes,I tried. It seems like my csv data have different column numbers,bu the schema is always same,like this:
csv data:
"3","130.180.138.56","Tunnel6","","0:0:0:0:0:0"
"1"
"2","130.180.138.56"
"2","130.180.138.56"

schema:
datainfo,ipaddress,nodename,location,time

Comment: are spark_core and spark_sql versions the same?

Comment: yes，both are 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to bee more complex than I had thought. And reasons are two in my occasion.
1.My dataset has a empty row which came from csv.In this case, I can create and show this dataset with the following code:

```
SparkSession ss = sparkContextManager.createThreadLocalSparkSession(functionId);
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(ss.sparkContext());
for (String fieldName : columns) {
     StructField field = DataTypes
                 .createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
     fields.add(field);
}
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
List<String[]> tmpContent = LocalFileUtilsCustomize.readCsv(tempPath);
List<Row> content = jsc.parallelize(tmpContent).map(l -> RowFactory.create((Object[])l)).collect();
Dataset<Row> searchInfo= ss.createDataFrame(content,schema);
searchInfo.show();
```

But when I tried to join two dataset and show them, I got this error.
Then I tried to remove blank lines, but still got error.
At least, I realized that I must ensure that all rows of csv have the same number of columns with 'schema' even if I set ' nullable=true'.
So solution of this question is like this:

```
SparkSession ss = sparkContextManager.createThreadLocalSparkSession(functionId);
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(ss.sparkContext());
for (String fieldName : columns) {
    StructField field = DataTypes
                .createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
    fields.add(field);
}
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
List<String[]> tmpContent = LocalFileUtilsCustomize.readCsv(tempPath);
List<Row> content = new ArrayList<>();
for(String[] s :tmpContent) {
                   Row r = null;
                   if(s[0].isEmpty() ) {
                       continue;
                   }
                   if(s.length < columns.size()) {
                       String[] tmpS = new String[columns.size()];
                       System.arraycopy(s, 0, tmpS, 0, s.length);
                       r = RowFactory.create((Object[])tmpS);
                   }else {
                       r = RowFactory.create((Object[])s);
                   }
                   content.add(r);
               }
Dataset<Row> searchInfo= ss.createDataFrame(content,schema);
searchInfo.show();
Dataset result = null;
result = deviceInfoDataset.join(searchInfo,deviceInfoDataset.col("deviceName").equalTo(searchInfo.col("deviceName")));
result.show();
```